# Solr Geo Query To Find Intersecting Radii of Objects

Tags: solr, solrj

I need to return all objects whose radii intersect. In other words, the addition of the radii of two objects is greater than the distance between them.

For example, let's say I have the following objects and my search center was A

```
A, radius=3k
B, radius=5k, distance from A = 6k
C, radius=15k, distance from A = 100k
```

Using the objects above, if my search center is object A, I need to return only object B. There could be thousands of objects in the system and the search center can be at any one of them.

I've implemented simple geo distance filtering with solr (i.e. give me everything 3k from A), but I'm not sure where to begin with this query. Is this possible to do with Solr? I have access to the data, so I can pre-calculate any necessary values to help with the query before loading the docs into solr. Also, I am using Solr 4.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

It just occurred to me that really what I need is to get the radius of A (the search center) and whatever other object being inspected within the query itself so I can use the difference between them. The query I'm using right now just returns anything within 3k of point x,y:

```
fl=*,_dist_:geodist()&fq={!geofilt}&pt=x,y&sfield=location&d=3&q=*:*
```

The `d=3` parameter needs to be something like `d=(doc1.radius + doc2.radius) >= _dist_`. I guess the question is how do I reference elements of the docs being compared within the query? And can I use the pseudo field `_dist_` as a value in the query?